# If Then strange error

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

I have very strange problem in VBA. I'm trying to compare 2 values, one is varible assigned from table (*AfterUpdate event on ComboBox*), and other one is value that user type in textbox on form.

```
nosivost = DLookup("max_nosivost", "tbl_vozila", "[registarska_oznaka]='" & Me.vozilo.Column(2) & "'")
If nosivost < Me.kolicina Then MsgBox "Some text", vbCritical, "Title"
```

`Me.vozilo` is name of ComboBox that displays records from tbl_vozila.
`Me.kolicina` is name of TextBox.

The problem is that I'm getting `MsgBox` every time, even if the `If-Then` statement is not true. For example, if I type 10 in TextBox and select record from ComboBox which have `max_nosivost = 30` i would still get MsgBox.

I checked value of variable `nosivost` and `DLookup` is returning correct value.

Answer (score 2):

Always do a vartype on variables. You are probably comparing a string and a number.

```
A=30
B="30"

'wont match
If A = B then msgbox "hi"

msgbox vartype(A)
Msgbox Vartype(B)
If Clng(A) = CLng(B) then msgbox "hi"
```

The values returned by vartype. Use

```
Return Values

Constant Value Description 
vbEmpty 0 Empty (uninitialized) 
vbNull 1 Null (no valid data) 
vbInteger 2 Integer 
vbLong 3 Long integer 
vbSingle 4 Single-precision floating-point number 
vbDouble 5 Double-precision floating-point number 
vbCurrency 6 Currency value 
vbDate 7 Date value 
vbString 8 String 
vbObject 9 Object 
vbError 10 Error value 
vbBoolean 11 Boolean value 
vbVariant 12 Variant (used only with arrays of variants) 
vbDataObject 13 A data access object 
vbDecimal 14 Decimal value 
vbByte 17 Byte value 
vbUserDefinedType 36 Variants that contain user-defined types 
vbArray 8192 Array
```